# Field name for Regression or Progression defects

Tags: defect-tracking

I am looking for a name for the field that will hold the following values:

- Regression
- Progression
- Stress

The field reflects if the defect is a Regression defect or Progression defect and so on.
In our defect management, we already use 'Type', so would be happy to get any other suggestions.

Thanks !

Comment: You can call it whatever you and your team are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

- Defect / Bug category
- Defect / Bug type
- Defect / Bug discovered by

Instead of using "type", I recommend to use a longer and more descriptive term. "Type" itself is too ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a name for the field that will hold the following
>   values:
>
> - Regression
> - Progression
> - Stress

Use the field name "Test Type".

Answer (score 1):

As field reflects the defect type, I think you should name it "Defect Type". It would look like as;

**Defect Type**

---

Regression
Progression
Stress

Type is not an option as already used and also too generic.